# Stopping time question $\sigma$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, stopping-times

If $S$ and $T$ are stopping time, $S \vee T$ is $\max ({S,T})$, $F_S$ and $F_T$ are stopped sigma algebra, show that $F_{S \vee T} = \sigma(F_S,F_T)$.

My thinking : I should take a set $A$ in $F_{S \vee T}$ and show it is in  $\sigma(F_S,F_T)$. I also notice that if $A$ is in $F_{S \vee T}$ then $A \cap\{S\le T\}$ is in $F_T$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A \in F_{S \vee T}$ and write

$$A = \underbrace{(A \cap [S \leq T])}_{=: A_T} \cup \underbrace{(A \cap [T \leq S])}_{=:A_S}.$$

We claim that $A_S \in F_S$ and $A_T \in F_T$. Indeed,

$$A_S \cap [S \leq t] = A \cap [T \leq S] \cap [S \leq t] = \underbrace{A \cap [S \vee T \leq t]}_{\in \mathcal{F}_t} \cap \underbrace{[T \leq S] \cap [S \leq t]}_{\in \mathcal{F}_t}$$

for any $t \geq 0$. Hence, $A_S \in F_S$. Similarly, $A_T \in F_T$. Consequently, we find $$A = A_S \cup A_T \in \sigma(F_S,F_T).$$

On the other hand, if $A \in F_S$, then

$$A \cap [S \vee T \leq t] = \underbrace{A \cap [S \leq t]}_{\in \mathcal{F}_t} \cap [S \vee T \leq t] \in \mathcal{F}_t.$$

This shows that $\sigma(F_S,F_T) \subseteq F_{S \vee T}$.

Comment: $A \cap [S \vee T \leq t] = \underbrace{A \cap [S \leq t]}_{\in \mathcal{F}_t} \cap [S \vee T \leq t] \in \mathcal{F}_t.$ , I am little bit confused about this last equality, how can you put the {S<=t} inside ?

Comment: @Peter If $S \vee T = \max\{S,T\} \leq t$, this implies automatically $S \leq t$.

Comment: Ah I see it now, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Dear @saz, I have a question about the second part of this proof. If $A \in F_S \cup F_T$, then clearly $A \in F_{S \vee T}$. But how do you arrive at   $$A \in \sigma(F_S \cup F_T) \implies A \in F_{S \vee T}$$
Surely, there is more in $\sigma(F_S \cup F_T)$ than in $F_S \cup F_T$. I thought if I can show that $F_S \cup F_T$ is a $\pi$-system (even though this is not true for any two sigma algebras), then the result would follow but didn't succeed at that.

Comment: @saz Oh I figured it out. $\sigma(F_S \cup F_T)$ is by definition the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $F_S \cup F_T$. Since $F_S \cup F_T \subset F_{S\vee T}$ and $F_{S\vee T}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma(F_S \cup F_T) \subset F_{S\vee T} $

Comment: @Calculon Yes, exactly.